# Why can't I make Selenium write a message in my WhatsApp Web using Python 3.8 and Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

So I use this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/N-Thalpy/Documents/NT/py/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options) 

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/") 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600) 


target = '"Batman"'

string = "Python 3.8"

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, x_arg))) 
group_title.click() 
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="_3u328"][@dir="ltr"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath))) 
for i in range(100): 
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER) 
    time.sleep(1)
```

And Chrome opens in web.whatsapp.com as expected - then it opens "Batman's" chat. However, it doesn't write anything. I checked the attributes and even tried to be more specific about them, but nothing seems to work. I tried it without sandbox option and still nothing.

**Edit**: the only message I get from the py.exe console is this:

"[13920:4684:0130/154024.795:ERROR:wmi_refresher.cc(129)] Unable to add the Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk enum."

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by:

- Downloading the **correct chromedriver version** as I was using Chrome 79 and using the driver for Chrome 80.
- Searching for ALL the attributes of the div, includin spellcheck, contenteditable and dir (I don't how relevant this actually is, but just in case).